# Servlet stripping parameter values because of # character

Tags: servlets, url-encoding, querystringparameter

My URL is `http://175.24.2.166/download?a=TOP#0;ONE=1;TWO2`.

How should I encode the parameter so that when I print the parameter in the Servlet, I get the value in its entirety? Currently when I print the value by using `request.getParameter("a")` I get the output as `TOP` instead of `TOP#0;ONE=1;TWO2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode it like this `http://175.24.2.166/download?a=TOP%230%3BONE%3D1%3BTWO2` . There are a lot of the encoders in Java, you can try to use [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) or [some online encoders](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) for experements

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the "fragment identifier".

as mentioned in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

The fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark # is the optional last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document.
the part after the # is info for the client. Put everything your client needs here.

you need to encode your query string.

you can use encodeURIComponent() function in JavaScript encodes a URI component.This function encodes special characters.